# How to check if a record already exists or not in database in DRF?

Tags: orm, django-rest-framework

I am working on DRF. I am creating an API of POST request that overriding its features. I want to add one functionality if a particular field value already exists in DB then, user cannot create post request and instead of it getting a message that he couldn't do it.

**views.py**

```
class PizzaOrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'put', 'patch', 'post']

   def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        order = PizzaOrder.objects.create(
                name=data['name'], flavours=data['flavours'],
                number=data['number'], size=data['size'],
                customer_name=data['customer_name'],
                customer_address=data['customer_address']
            )
        order.save()
        serializer = PizzaOrderSerializer(order)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PizzaOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = PizzaOrder
       validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=PizzaOrder.objects.all(),
                fields=['name', 'flavours', 'size', 'customer_name', 'customer_address'],
                message='This field should be unique'
            )
        ]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime


FLAVOURS_CHOICE = (
    ('Margarita', 'Margarita'),
    ('Marinara', 'Marinara'),
    ('Salami', 'Salami'),
)

SIZE_CHOICE = (
    ('Small', 'Small'),
    ('Medium', 'Medium'),
    ('Large', 'Large'),
)

STATUS_CHOICE = (
    ('Open', 'Open'),
    ('Accepted', 'Accepted'),
    ('Preparing', 'Preparing'),
    ('OnWay', 'OnWay'),
    ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
)


class PizzaOrder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    flavours = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=FLAVOURS_CHOICE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SIZE_CHOICE)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    customer_address = models.TextField(blank=False)
    ordered_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, editable=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, default='Open')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-ordered_time']
        unique_together = ('name', 'flavours', 'quantity', 'size')
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: The easiest thing to do might be to set a `unique` constraint on the model field itself or a `unique_together` on multiple fields.

Comment: Use [field level validators](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#field-level-validation)

Comment: @RossRogers I tried but it fails, can you please write code for me, for better understanding

Comment: @ManishPal , what does you Model or models look like?

Comment: @RossRogers I just edit and add modes.py file in question.

Comment: You can have multiple `unique_together` elements and I think this would achieve your goal:  `unique_together = [ ['name', 'flavours', 'quantity', 'size'], [ 'name', 'flavours', 'size', 'customer_name', 'customer_address'] ]` .  Then, you need to run `python manage.py  makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`